# Masstransit inconsistent exception from request client

Tags: masstransit

I'm using the request client to send synchronous request to my consumer, and in my consumer I'm throwing an exception.

My code looks like this

```
var client = Bus.CreateRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(uri, Timeout);
try
{
   var response = await client.Request(request);
}
Catch(Exception e)
{
   //log
}
```

The issue is if I repeat the request in quick succession, sometimes I catch the real exception that's thrown in the consumer inside RequestFaultException, sometimes I catch the MassTransit.RequestCanceledException. I'm certain it's not caused by time out as it's set to a long time span (30s). Am I doing something wrong?

Stack trace:

> MassTransit.RequestCanceledException: The request was canceled, RequestId: 00240000-ac12-0242-0947-08d7b68e88f0 ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
>      at MassTransit.Internals.Extensions.TaskExtensions.WithCancellation(Task task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendTransport.SendPipe`1.Send(ModelContext modelContext)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendTransport.SendPipe`1.Send(ModelContext modelContext)
>      at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MassTransit.Clients.SendRequestSendEndpoint`1.Send(T message, IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MassTransit.Clients.ClientRequestHandle`1.SendRequest()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MassTransit.Clients.ClientRequestHandle`1.SendRequest()
>      at MassTransit.Clients.ResponseHandlerConnectHandle`1.GetTask()
>      at MassTransit.MessageRequestClient`2.Request(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: There was a concurrency issue that was fixed in the latest (v6.2) release - you might give that a try and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Chris Patterson, I was on 5.5, the issue is fixed in v6.2.